# put negative integer value in edit box in MFC?

Tags: mfc

How to put negative integer value in edit box in MFC ?

I tried using Cstring and then changing it to integer using _aoti()

Comment: How is the edit box defined?  Please show some code.

Comment: Yeah i found a solution!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I found a way to put negative numbers in the edit box .
    here is the following code

```
//add a macro 

#define INVALID_INT_MSG_EX  L"Enter an integer between %d and %d."

//declare a global variable 
 int flag_for_negative_numbers = 0

void CTouchPanelModule::OnEnChangeTpTempValue()
{
    UpdateData(true);
    if (editBoxVariable_value == _T('-') && (flag_for_negative_numbers == 0))
        {
            flag_for_negative_numbers = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int tempValueTouchPanel_value = _wtoi(editBoxVariable_value);
                ValidateEditCtrl(ID_of_the_edit_box,
                editBoxVariable_value,
                MIN_value,
                MAX_value, default_value);
        }
}

//Below is the defination of ValidateEditCtrl() function

bool CustomDialogEx::ValidateEditCtrl(int CtrlId, int& valueToCheck, int minValue, int maxValue, CString defaultValue)
{
    auto isValid = true;
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    if (valueToCheck < minValue || valueToCheck > maxValue)
    {
        CString cString;
        cString.Format(INVALID_INT_MSG_EX, minValue, maxValue);
        ChangeMessageBoxTitle appTitle(dlgTitle);
        AfxMessageBox(cString);
        GetDlgItem(CtrlId)->SetWindowText(defaultValue);
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```